# how to use search bars with core data?

Tags: xcode, search, core-data, uisearchbar

How do you use search bars with core data?
I have the search bar appearing above the tableview but currently it is not working
I need to be able to search through a list of meals
I'm quite new to xcode so if u could give details answers such as which method to put code etc it would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

follow this tutorial 
[core data search tutorial](http://timroadley.com/2012/03/05/core-data-basics-part-7-search-bars/)

you can also check my git project, I just done use search bar with core data:
https://github.com/dennis87/bookList

if you have questions about the project ask me and I will try to answer you (I am new too).